# why i have to use an include_path directory for phpmailer?

Tags: php

I am learning PHP.
Try using phpmailer and succeed.
but to import the classes just throw the folder in the project folder
and it worked.
why in the documentation readme
it says I should use `include_path` directory to use phpmailer.

Is it for security?.

I am using xammp to learn, but
if I use phpmailer in production should it always be in include_path?

the default is pear folder , can I create another one for phpmailer and then add it to php.ini
or should I use that (pear) for security or something like that ?

the readme of phpmailer:

```
Alternatively, if you're not using Composer, copy the contents of the PHPMailer folder into one of the `include_path` directories specified in your PHP configuration and load each class file manually:
```

im not using composer

Comment: Might help if you included a link to the documentation you're referencing. The current way to use any PHP package is autoloading. Check into composer.

Comment: @EternalHour  "Alternatively, if you're not using Composer, copy the contents of the PHPMailer folder into one of the `include_path` directories specified in your PHP configuration and load each class file manually: "